# Angular animation js doesn't work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="testAn" ng-repeat="a in b">{{a}}</div>
```

I created simple array `b = [1,2,3];`
I used angular js 1.6.5 and animation 1.6.5 before I tried with 1.6.4
All tests made on localhost

Animate connected to js 'ngAnimated. The problem is it doesn't add any classes to ng-repeat elements.

Comment: HTML code "<div class="testAn" ng-repeat="a in b ">{{a}}</div>"

Comment: Could you post your controller code pls? Do you have ng-controller set in the template?

Comment: please post the js code along with html too

Comment: App.controller('faq',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.b = [1,2];}).

Comment: App.controller('faq', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { $scope.b = [1,2]; }]);

Comment: Ok I found out that ng-animate add classes if you add to array but doesn't add when array already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that ng-animate add classes if you add to array but doesn't add when array already exist.

But now another problem.Why it doesn't animate first element in ng-repat?

Comment: Also if it's list(<ul><.li ng-repeat=...></li><ul>) everything works fine but if its div or button animate doesn't work for the first element

Answer (score 0):

Everything is work. Question is closed.